# Is it possible to get my data back from a single data file without control files and system tablespace?

Tags: docker, oracle11g, database-restore

I lost the system tablespace and database control files permanently and there's no RMAN backup.

I only have a single database file copied from the docker container which had been destroyed permanently.

Is it possible to restore the data in the data file and how?

Answer (score 0):

The *only* option I am aware of for your situation would be the use of Oracle's Data UnLoader (DUL) utility, which is only available by contracting their professional services consultants (not cheap). Short of that I don't believe there is any way to recover your data.

Answer (score 0):

dbrecover for oracle can directly unload data from single datafile ,even you lost all other datafiles including system tablespace datafile . you can reference this video : https://youtu.be/iJNxy4WkA08

[image: row data from single datafile]